# can an asp.net user control determin membership provider role of a user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have an admin panel with a left nav section made of Li's that run at server.
The thing had matured over time to the point certain items are viewable by admins only.

I have all the code already working and wanted to clean it up by making a Nav user control, but have issues in detecting the user's role or any user info that i had access to directly on the page.

sample HTML code from my Nav:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Configuration;

namespace PolyWeb.AdminPanel
{
    public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public bool isAdminView;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            isAdminView = User.IsInRole("admin");

            lblLogedInUser.Text += User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

smaple codebehind:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked main-menu">
        <li class="nav-header hidden-tablet">Main</li>
        <li runat="server" id="LiAdminNavRoles" visible="<%# isAdminView %>" ><a class="ajax-link" href="/Admin/access/roles.aspx"><i class="icon-home"></i><span class="hidden-tablet red"> RolesAdmin Page</span></a></li>
    </ul>
```

when I try this same thing in a user control (.ascx) it doesn’t work, even with all the security namespaces imported like the .aspx page.

How can I get a handle on User from a UserCOntrol to do the same show/ hiding of elements in the Navigation?

Comment: Try "Page.User.IsInRole" or "HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole" from within your UserControl.

Comment: i get the following error: The name 'isAdminView' does not exist in the current context. the variable is set as public above the page load of the user control. then in page load of user control i assign it isAdminView = Page.User.IsInRole("admin");

Comment: shouldnt i be able to do soemthing liek this: <li runat="server" id="LiAdminNavRoles" visible="<%# Eval ( Page.User.IsInRole(&nbsp;admin&nbsp; ) )  %>" ><a class="ajax-link" href="/Admin/access/roles.aspx"><i class="icon-home"></i><span class="hidden-tablet red"> RolesAdmin Page</span></a></li>